# Send token from 2Captcha API to solve Hcaptcha using Python Selenium Chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, captcha

I am trying to solve the Hcaptcha page on a website protected by Cloudfare

Website to access : https://carmanuals2.com/mazda/3-hatchback-2020-owner-s-manual-114463

I followed the instruction on Recatcha API and able to get token that are suppose to be placed in these two fields:

```
<textarea id="g-recaptcha-response-0418tkobioj8" name="g-recaptcha-response" style="display: none;"></textarea>
```

```
<textarea id="h-captcha-response-0418tkobioj8" name="h-captcha-response" style="display: none;"></textarea>
```

API Documentation : https://2captcha.com/2captcha-api#solving_hcaptcha

Next step is to place the tokens on these two elements, However, I get a error as
`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`

Here is a snipppet of my code, where I try to place the token I received (captcha)

```
        sitekey = site["src"].split("=")[-1]
        
        currenturl = driver.current_url
        print (currenturl)


        flag, captcha = solve_h_captcha(sitekey,currenturl)

        username = driver.find_element_by_name('g-recaptcha-response')
        username.send_keys(captcha)
        time.sleep(2)
        
        username = driver.find_element_by_name('h-captcha-response')
        username.send_keys(captcha)
        time.sleep(2)

#        username.send_keys(captcha)
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to do things like that from js:

```
driver.execute_script("""
  let [captcha] = arguments
  document.querySelector('[name="h-captcha-response"]').innerHTML = captcha
  document.querySelector('[name="g-captcha-response"]').innerHTML = captcha
""", captcha)
```

Comment: With hcaptcha does not work. Selenium response: Message: unknown error: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null